# Map a function over a vector

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I have the following `x` and `y`:

```
set.seed(1234)
x <- seq(1, 1000, 1)
y <- rnorm(1000)
```

And I need to model them using `smooth.spline`:

```
model <- smooth.spline(x, y, nknots = 10)
```

The problem is that I need to fit this model modifying `nknots` every time. The vector indicating the knots is the following:

```
myknots <- seq(5, 15, 1)
```

I thought creating my own function, like:

```
myfoo <- function(x, y, nknots){
  smooth.spline(x, y, nknots = nknots)
}
```

But I can't find a straight way of doing it. I rather use the `purrr` package. Any ideas?

Comment: you can do `lapply(myknots, function(k) myfoo(x=x,y=x,nknots=k))`

Comment: Your function `myfoo` isn't helping. You can do `lapply(myknots, function(k){smooth.spline(x=x,y=y,nknots=k)})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `purrr`, we use `map`

```
library(purrr)
map(myknots,  ~ myfoo(x, y, nknots = .x))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this without needing the added burden of loading extra packages and relying on them to never change using base::Vectorize in a one-liner:

```
> alls = Vectorize(smooth.spline,"nknots",SIMPLIFY=FALSE)(x=x,y=y,nknots=myknots)
```

This returns a list where each element is a `smooth.spline` output for each value of `myknots`:

```
> alls[[1]]
Call:
(function (x, y = NULL, w = NULL, df, spar = NULL, lambda = NULL, 
    cv = FALSE, all.knots = FALSE, nknots = .nknots.smspl, keep.data = TRUE, 
  ...

Smoothing Parameter  spar= 0.1318881  lambda= 0.01540768 (14 iterations)
Equivalent Degrees of Freedom (Df): 5.244268
Penalized Criterion (RSS): 984.4824
GCV: 0.99489
> alls[[2]]
Call:
(function (x, y = NULL, w = NULL, df, spar = NULL, lambda = NULL, 
    cv = FALSE, all.knots = FALSE, nknots = .nknots.smspl, keep.data = TRUE, 
  ...

Smoothing Parameter  spar= 0.2285265  lambda= 0.03658625 (12 iterations)
Equivalent Degrees of Freedom (Df): 5.006371
Penalized Criterion (RSS): 984.8108
GCV: 0.994746
```

Keeping dependencies to a minimum is good practice.